# Compare 2 csv file with 1 column each in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have to compare 2 csv files where each file got 1 column:

file1.csv:

column1

9788800000000
9788800000001
9788800000002
9788800000003
...

file2.csv:

column1

9788800000000
9788800000001
9788800000002
9788800000006
9788800000007
9788800000008
...

I have to do something when some EAN code isn't found in the second csv file (file2.csv). For example the code 9788800000003 it's ONLY present in file1.csv.

Now, I have to update a table in DB when an EAN code in the first file, isn't found in the second file and set it to '0' (in this case, the ean 9788800000003 have to be change in 0 quantity):

mysql_query("UPDATE $update_table SET quantity='0' WHERE ean13='$ean13'")

how to compare the column for differences ?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$file1 = file('file1.csv');
$file2 = file('file2.csv');

$diff  = array_diff($file1, $file2);
$list  = implode(',', $diff);

$query = "UPDATE $update_table SET quantity='0' WHERE ean13 IN ($list)";
```

1. Read files into an array of lines
2. Get an array of the differences
3. Generate a list of the EAN differences
4. Use IN in the WHERE clause

Comment: Thank you. It works good. Only 1 thing: is there for not "count" the order ? If I insert in the first file: 

766623917236
766623917237
766623917235 

and in second file:

766623917235
766623451178
766623917230
766623917236
766623917237

It gives : 766623917237 ,766623917235. But These 2 codes are present in both files. thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but the other option is `array_intersect`

Comment: In practice, I have to know which EAN code is not present in the second file. I insert codes one per line in both files like the post i have done. In the first there are the ean codes available in the shop, and I have to compare with the second file which is provided by our supplier. Now if the supplier delete a code (and I have it in my shop, into file1.csv) I have to know it and replace the quantity to 0, because it becomes unavailable.

Comment: I think that we are very close to the solution.. any clue ?

Comment: I added a `$diff2  = array_diff($file2, $file1);` which help to find differences in reverse way. Now I have to execute the *$query* for update quantity with **$update_table, only IF the ean13 codes output of $diff and $diff2 are FOUND in DB**. How to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: You should start a new question with all of the detail.